# get random result of Tire::Results::Collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, elasticsearch, tire

I have inside this variable `@results` a `Tire::Results::Collection` with many results.

How can I get **1 random result** of this `Tire::Results::Collection`

**Thanks!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Ruby 1.9, just use the `Array#sample` method:

```
p [1, 2, 3].sample

# -----

require 'tire'
s = Tire.search { query { all } }

p s.results.to_a.sample
```

Comment: @karmi How well does this work if the index contains thousands of results? Doesn't it have to load them all into memory?

Comment: @gmcnaughton The question was about handful of hits loaded in @results. To get a random document from ES index, google & research the `function_score` query.